# Probability of having 3 different intersection points when 3 stakes are thrown at random

Tags: probability

What it the probability of having three different intersection points when three random stakes are thrown.

I guess when throwing three stakes only the following cases can happen

- Three parallel stakes forming no points.
- Two parallel stakes and one secant forming two points.
- No parallel stakes and all pass by one point.
- No parallel stakes and all intersect in different points with each other forming three points.

If these are all the possible outcomes, then the probability of having 3 points, I guess should be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Just to let you know, in American English a steak is a piece of meat. Perhaps you meant stakes?

Comment: "three random stakes are thrown". Don't you mean "three stakes are thrown at random"?

Comment: It seems to me that these probabilities may well depend on the conditions under which the stake throwing process takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it has no sense to say that the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$ just because there are 4 possible outcomes (imagine a box with 9 white balls and one black ball; if you take one, it may be white or black, but the outcomes do not have the same probability).

In fact, in a probability-theoretical sense, it all depends on the probability distribution you give beforehand. But for any reasonable probability distribution for your problem, the probability of three different points of intersection is 1 ('the other possibilities have zero measure', if talking technically).

Comment: If the stakes are landing on a sufficiently large but finite affine plane then I think some of those events may have non-zero probability. But I highly doubt the OP had any such model in mind.